# Difference in accessing pixel by at and by data OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

Today I observed one interesting thing: if I access image pixel using the function 'at' I received different result then if I access image pixel using image member 'data'. 
Does anybody know why it happened?

```
int main()
{
    double sigma = 1.0;
    cv::Mat verticalGaussianKernel = getGaussianKernel(7, sigma);
    printImg(verticalGaussianKernel);
    return 0;
}
void printImg(cv::Mat &img)
{
    cout << "---------//------\n";
    if (img.empty())
    {
        cout << "Empty Image\n";
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < img.size().height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < img.size().width; j++)
        {
            cout << int(img.data[i * img.size().height + j]) << " " << img.at<double>(i, j) << endl;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << "---------//------\n";
}
```

it code gives results:

> data-------at
>   48------0.00443305
>   63------0.0540056
>   171-----0.242036
>   251-----0.39905
>   10------0.242036
>   12------0.0540056
>   84------0.00443305

Firstly I thought that values in data normalizing to 0-255, but the last string refute my guess

Comment: it's data[i*width + j] but this formula is only correct for continuous single channel 8 bit matrices. In general you should use widthStep parameter and to cate abour the type is more complicated. Use row-Pointers for more efficiency and less error prone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your casting is wrong. The .data member is an uchar*, you're dereferencing it and casting that value (a single uchar) to int thats why you're not getting the correct values.

The proper way to do it would be to cast it to a double* and then dereferencing it. The following code does that.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

void printImg(cv::Mat &img) {
    cout << "---------//------\n";
    if (img.empty()) {
        cout << "Empty Image\n";
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < img.rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < img.cols; j++) {
                 cout << reinterpret_cast<double *>(img.data)[i * img.cols + j]
                 << " " << img.at<double>(i, j) << endl;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << "---------//------\n";
}

int main() {
    double sigma = 1.0;
    cv::Mat verticalGaussianKernel = getGaussianKernel(7, sigma);
    cout << verticalGaussianKernel << endl;
    printImg(verticalGaussianKernel);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
[0.004433048175243745;
 0.05400558262241448;
 0.2420362293761143;
 0.3990502796524549;
 0.2420362293761143;
 0.05400558262241448;
 0.004433048175243745]
---------//------
0.00443305 0.00443305

0.0540056 0.0540056

0.242036 0.242036

0.39905 0.39905

0.242036 0.242036

0.0540056 0.0540056

0.00443305 0.00443305
```

Answer (score 0):

You are reading the data as a char . Instead, read it as a double

```
int main()
{
    double sigma = 1.0;
    cv::Mat verticalGaussianKernel = getGaussianKernel(7, sigma);
    printImg(verticalGaussianKernel);
    return 0;
}
void printImg(cv::Mat &img)
{
    cout << "---------//------\n";
    if (img.empty())
    {
        cout << "Empty Image\n";
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < img.size().height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < img.size().width; j++)
        {
            cout << double(img.data[i * img.size().height*sizeof(double) + j*sizeof(double)]) << " " << img.at<double>(i, j) << endl;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << "---------//------\n";
}
```

Comment: when I change double to uchar the output is  seven zeros

Comment: i guess the gaussian kernel un fact is double type. So accessing by .data without conversion of the row pointer is wrong.

Comment: Aah my bad...I did it the other way around. Try now.